# Strange UI bugs in Swift

Tags: swift

I have been experiencing a slew of assorted, strange UI bugs that I have no idea how to approach at this point. [Here are some of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKqk2.gif). Notice the backgroundColor of the UITextFields changing back to white when pushing to a new ViewController, and the random movement/jumping of other elements (the signup button when being pushed to the Forgot Password VC jumps down; hard to see because of the gif compression), as though the constraints are changing - they are not.

Here's a sample of my code that styles one of the fields:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.emailField.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    emailField.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
    emailField.textColor = Constants.Colors.text
    emailField.setBottomBorder(color: Constants.Colors.gray1, height: 2)
```

It's part of a styleElements() function that I call within viewWillAppear(). The rest of my elements in all my other VC's are styled in the same way. The reason I'm dispatching the backgroundColor styling to the main thread is because otherwise it doesn't even get called, also another mystery bug.

I only noticed the UITextField issue when adapting my app to dark mode, and have tried looking for a solution to the rest for weeks but I can't find a single instance of someone else having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a mystery: you need to perform all ui updates on the main queue.  If you do not do this then the behavior is, as you have discovered, undefined.  This is because the system needs to marshall a large amount of information to send to the GPU to render.  You can not just change this information whenever you want, or you may change the data while the system is getting ready for a draw call and then the wrong or inconsistent information will be sent to the GPU.  By dispatching the draw calls to the main queue, you allow the system to block the main queue when it needs to so that it can insure that nothing gets mutated while its working on assembling everything for the next draw.

Answer (score 0):

While creating an application, you must make sure that all the UI related code is run on the main thread while the heavy stuffs like fetching data basically the networking code must be run on a background thread. For your reference, following is the link to an [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker] article in the Apple site where it is clearly mentioned that if the developer runs the UI code in the background thread then that may lead to UI defects which happened in this case.